# Webkit mask moving when scrolling on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I've been trying to make a rounded google map. I've finally achieved it and here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DZTvR/13/

The problem is in chrome when I scroll, the mask remains in the same place while the map scrolls down.

I have tested on FF, opera safari and IE and it works great. It's just chrome

The HTML is

```
<div id="wrapp">
      <div id="mask">
            <div id="anyotherID"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The JS

```
window.onload=function(){
    var myLatlngDist = new google.maps.LatLng(-32.242741,-60.161446);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var mapOptionsDist = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlngDist,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    mapDist = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('anyotherID'), mapOptionsDist);
}
```

The CSS

```
#anyotherID{
    height:427px;
    width:428px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1000px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1000px;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mask {
    border-radius: 1000px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1000px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 1000px;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: absolute; /* this breaks the overflow:hidden in Chrome/Opera */
     /* this fixes the overflow:hidden in Chrome */
    -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to finally work here is how I fixed it

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapp">
   <div id="mask">
       <div id="anyotherID"></div>
   </div>
       <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var mapOptionsDist = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    }
}
mapLoc = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('anyotherID'), mapOptionsDist);
```

And the css:

```
#anyotherID{
    height:427px;
    width:427px;
}
#mask {
    border-radius: 1000px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1000px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1000px;
    height:427px;
    width:427px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute; /* this breaks the overflow:hidden in Chrome/Opera */
    -webkit-mask-image: url("/Resources/Image/px.png");
}
#wrapp{
    height:427px;
    width:427px;
    float:left;
}
```

Just to clarify, the image px.png is just an image of a black pixel, without it, it won't work